# Class props are empty while test it via enzyme mount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Doing next step:

```
let wrapper;
let container;
let store = mockStore(initialState);
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component />
        </Provider>,
    );
    container = wrapper.find(Component);
    console.log("props:",container.props(),"\nstate:",container.state())
});
```

I expect to see in console props which I wrote in the store and passed them using mapStateToProps, but i see empty object instead. Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong, please ? 
P.S. right now Component is simple class, if i'm starting using HOC (via connect) i can't reach my Component at all

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing the component without the connect HOC. Then you will never get to see the props from mapStateToProps as the component you've imported doesn't run the connect function.

You would need to import the connected component and then wrap it in the provider. `wrapper` should then have everything you need.

-

Edit: If there's no way to get access to the connected component, simply use the component and declare all the props manually.

Something like this:

```
import { Foo } from '../foo';

const props = {
  title: 'Hello',
  subTitle: 'World'
};

describe('<Foo />', () => {
  test('should make props available', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Foo {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.props).toEqual(props);
  });
});
```

Comment: yes , but in this case i can't get access to connected component inside Provider

Comment: You need to import the whole component to your test file. If you can't get access to the connected component than there isn't a way to access the store unless you manually provide all the props. I'll update my answer.